# Tonsil pain after singing: could be tension?

Tags: voice, voice-training, pain

I'm a beginner in singing, and I'm learning right now how to use/work with the support for the diaphragm (I'm sorry if this is not the best way to describe the technique, but I don't know how it is called in English).
I'm studying with a teacher that is able to tell me if I'm using the diaphragm wrong or not using at all and stops me when it's necessary.
Recently happened that after singing (not while singing, but a few hours later maybe and the day after) I could feel a sort of pain in my left tonsil if I touch it with the tongue.
It's not like a sore throat because it is not stinging when I swallow, it is not that. It just "hurt" when I press it with the tongue as if it's an aching muscle.
Could it be just some tension, or is it something else? Because I also feel some tension in the neck, some caused by other factors of stress.
I'm also trying to adjust my posture, I sometimes bent over my chest during exercises, I'm having some issues to stay always upright because I have this bad habit of staying a little curved, caused by an office work.
I'm a little worried about this. Is it a normal error for beginner or is something else?

Comment: you say you have a teacher, why not ask the teacher?

Comment: In this season it will be rather an infection HNO)

Answer (score 1):

I have this every autumn when the rainy foggy weather begins and  I’m caught cold. Don’t run to the doctor for this!

Some cups of tea (Thymian)  or chewing the leaves of Salbei or Echinacea will help you to overcome this deadly illness.

N.b. these plants contain natural antibiotics. If they don’t help it might be a virus and the you just can wait and drink tea - about  for two weeks.

Maybe, as you are concentrated on singing  you are breathing in more bacterias?

**Edit:**

To those who think you should visit the doctor:

Look in the mirror and control whether you have tonsillitis or stones (yellow dots). Ask a good friend or someone of your family whether you have bad breath.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonsillolith

Comment: Yeah, could be. I woke up with a cold and throat ache this morning and the pain went away (this is 2nd day after singing lesson). But it happened in the past without getting a cold after. It could have been that it was coming and was aching for that, but I'll keep an eye on this if it happens again. Thanks for the tips, btw!

Comment: I'd have given this a -1 except for the "don't go crying to the doctor" comment. Life happens, live with it.

Comment: What do you mean, Tetsujin? Do I understand you right: you would have down-voted this answer but you agree with "don't run to the doctor"?

Comment: Any professional singer or aspiring professional singer should develop a relationship with an ENT in order to learn more about proper voice care and technique. If you believe this is "crying to the doctor" then I pray you don't teach voice lessons. And if you believe the OP is simply sick, well that's what doctors are for ...

Comment: @NickGrooves: I’ve been singing teacher for all my life and I could tell you my story about tonsillitis and sinusitis and the sories of 100reds of my students. But  this would fill a book. So the resumé in 2 - 3 sentences: Tonsillectomy’s can be compared with the “ectomy” of an oil lamp in the car. (This indicates that your motoroil is empty. The tonsilles are indicator to tell you that body is stressed, infected or social psychologically.)  Antibiotics are only weakening your immun system and your self healing forces. And if one day you should really need them the bacteria are resistent.

Answer (score 0):

It is *not* normal to experience pain when singing. You should see an ENT and get a baseline image of your vocal folds. Here is a link to a major US hospital's voice center, which includes conditions and treatments descriptions:

- [Emory University Voice Center](https://www.emoryhealthcare.org/centers-programs/voice-center/index.html)

Edited to add: This advice and this link was shared with me (and many others) at a public industry convention years ago by Jan Smith, leading voice coach to multiple GRAMMY-winning artists. Please see a doctor!

Comment: :* Please see a doctor!*. Do you possess stocks and shares of this hospital or of the national health and care center?

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli No. I do not own any stocks or shares of this hospital. They are widely regarded in the Southeastern US as the leading voice center. Also, their website is very informative. I benefit in no way from sharing this information nor did I encourage the OP to give them any money. Why have I received a downvote for providing a helpful answer? What the heck is wrong with people on this exchange!?

Comment: Oh, this was just a joke ;) and I didn’t vote you down. I really only downvote something when the answer is objective wrong and I can **proof** it. And then I tell it to the author. Anonymous and unfounded (lacking of arguments)  downvoting is a really big faiblesse (weakness) of this SE! By the way I’ve just looked up your site and I see they are specialized for problems of larynx yes, and the other problems. If you have such a center in each town maybe it will benefiting  a professional singing student to consult them about his voice etc.